# What is the process for sending a axios POST method using reactjs to a node path?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, axios, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to send a POST request using axios to the backend but it is throwing a 404 for the path and i dont know why

Here is the react/redux code calling the axios request

```
export const addGoal = (newGoal: Goal) => {
  return (dispatch: any) => {
    authMiddleWare(history)
    const newValues = newGoal
    const authToken = localStorage.getItem('AuthToken')
    axios.defaults.headers.common = { Authorization: `${authToken}` }
    axios
      .post('/goal', newValues)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('success', response.data)
        dispatch({
          type: ADD_GOAL,
          payload: response.data,
        })
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error('\nCould not submit goal\n', err.response)
      })
  }
}
```

This is the nodejs path i have in my main backend file for calling the paths

```
app.post("/goal", auth, postOneGoal);
```

This is the backend function for the node path

```
// ADDS A SINGLE WORKOUT

exports.postOneGoal = (request, response) => {
  if (request.body.id.trim() === "" || request.body.text.trim() === "") {
    return response.status(400).json({ body: "Must not be empty" });
  }

  const newGoalItem = {
    username: request.user.username,
    id: request.body.id,
    text: request.body.text
  };

  db.collection("goals")
    .add(newGoalItem)
    .then((doc) => {
      const responseNewGoalItem = newGoalItem;
      responseNewGoalItem.id = doc.id;
      doc.update(responseNewGoalItem);
      return response.json(responseNewGoalItem);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      response.status(500).json({ error: "Couldn't add the goal" });
      console.error(err);
    });
};
```

I am using a firebase url proxy in my package.json as well.

Let me know if any more info is needed

Comment: are you using firebase hosting and/or function?

Comment: I am using firebase functions. Do I have to redeploy them when i add a new route?

Comment: You have to redeploy any time there is a change in code.

Comment: if you are using the local server during development, doesnt it refresh on its own?

Comment: If you want to test it on the localhost, i suggest to go with firebase [emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as Community Wiki, based in the comments.

Considering the fact that you are using Cloud Functions, you will need to redeploy the functions everytime you update your code. You can check more details on deploying your functions in the official documentation accessible [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying). There you will have the options regarding how and where you can deploy your functions for better testing.